# Get MANIFEST.MF path in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I want to read the MANIFEST.MF from my web appliation (I previously populated it with additional attributes). In JSF I could easily retrieve that path value with the FacesContext. How do you accomplish the same with Struts2 using a static call?

```
File manifestFile = null;
//JSF Context
String homePath = "EMPTY";
//homePath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/");
// HOW DO I RETRIEVE THE homePath VALUE OF THE WAR FILE?
java.util.jar.Manifest manifest = null;
manifestFile = new File(homePath, "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

The static call from a JSP Struts2 page works, but does not return any values, of course, because the `manifestFile` is null.

```
<s:property value='@ch.ejpd.admin.ManifestReader@getAppVersion()'/>
```

Comment: Where is the location of the `MANIFEST.MF` file. You didn't specify that in your question?

Comment: Why do you want the manifest file?

Comment: It's useful for reading version information or any other build-specific info that may be added during the build process (e.g., git branch or changeset hash, build time, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you understand what a `javax.servlet.ServletContext` is in a `web application`, you can get it in your action class by implementing `ServletContextAware` interface. This interface i.e. `javax.servlet.ServletContext` provides APIs like `getContextPath()`, `getRealPath(String path)`, `getResource(String path)`, `getResourceAsStream(String path)` etc. This APIs can help you get what you want. Try reading `javadoc` on this APIs to get better understanding. The way to implement the interface is

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletContextAware
{

    private ServletContext servletCtx;

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext context)
    {
        this.servletCtx = context;
    }

    public String execute()
    {
        //Use the servletCtx variable to perform your logic here
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do that, though Struts2 provide a clean way to get access to `ServletContext`  as described by `Uchenna`.

one way to access this

```
String relativePath = "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
String diskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativePath );
File file = new File(diskPath);
```

You can get access to `ServletContext` by implementing `ServletContextAware`.
Another way is to access it as `InputStream` with the help of `getResourceAsStream()`like

```
InputStream is= getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
```

As Steven mentioned in comment, prefer `getResourceAsStream()` since `getRealPath()` can be null for unexploded war.

Comment: You're better off using `getResourceAsStream()`. `getRealPath()` can return null if your application is running from an unexploded war.

Comment: @StevenBenitez: Agree with you,Thanks for pointer as i overlooked it